# Is it possible to convert Hello.World to ["Hello"]["World"]?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there is a way to convert example:

**'Hello.World'** into **'["Hello"]["World"]'** *or* **'This.is.a.string'** into **["This"]["is"]["a"]["string"]**

I'm kinda new to C# and I was wondering if that's even possible using string formatting or something like that.

Comment: [`string.Concat("Hello.World".Split('.').Select(x => $"[\"{x}\"]"))`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOwD4AEBMAjALABQuADAAS6EB0AMgJaYCOA3GQQMxUDeZKkJr58/QcMm0AnAApaFOgGEA9pgDGEGLIBEACTgAbQyroB1FQkMATHXQDKAB0NNtAcjpuAlA6Nx12gAeVAC8AHxUACQ6ANoAOjp8gQC+CQC6Ol5ZnKSSyWTJQA===)

Comment: [`Regex.Replace("Hello.World", @"([^.]+)\.?", "[\"$1\"]")`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOwD4AEBMAjALABQuADAAS6EB0AMgJaYCOA3GZTfQCpwAPGHQBKcAOboANhAQBRAQAcEcKFCYB7TFE7l8AZioBvMlTM18+Y6fO3aATgAUY8YNFxFMgMZxHAIgAJOCkpDToAdQ0EKQATPyQaXD9HAG0APToAXQBqAEoAHToAfniqPxT8vwASQkrMv1zc3VsAXzIWoA=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Split` method like this `string[] strings = String.Split(".");` This will split your string per each period.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant to include the single quotes (') as part of the string then:

```
String test = "'Hello.World'";
// Strip the first and last '
test = test.Substring(1, test.Length - 2);
// Split on Period
String[] split = test.Split('.');
// Encapsulate each word with [" "]
// and add back in the single quotes
var result = $"'{String.Join("", split.Select(word => $"[\"{word}\"]"))}'";
```

Prints:
'["Hello"]["World"]'

If they just meant to surround your input then just:

```
String test = "Hello.World";
// Split on Period
String[] split = test.Split('.');
// Encapsulate each word with [" "]
var result = $"{String.Join("", split.Select(word => $"[\"{word}\"]"))}";
```

Prints: ["Hello"]["World"]